# C# Entity Framework - Double relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and ASP.Net. I'm currently working on a small project on my own, and I was trying to implement Inbox feature. A Message from the Inbox has a sender and a receiver and this is expressed with a double relationship. This is waht I've done so far, but for some reason, the receiver is always null:

```
public class UserDB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Password {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("From")]
    public virtual List<MessageDB> Incoming { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("To")]
    public virtual List<MessageDB> Outgoing { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MessageDB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Incoming")]
    public UserDB From { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Outgoing")]
    public UserDB To { get; set; }
}
```

As I said, for some reason, the receiver (To from MessageDB) is always null, but I already checked the database and everything is ok in there.

Thanks!

Comment: show us how you query the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LazyLoading to work, you must declare the non-primitive properties on your models as virtual. This allows entity framework to implement them with its magic.

```
[InverseProperty("Incoming")]
public virtual UserDB From { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Outgoing")]
public virtual UserDB To { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it. I feel stupid now, that was some obvious mistake. I though I was missing something more complicated and did not noticed this very simple mistake. Man, I feel dumb. Many thanks!

Comment: No no, we all do it. Won't be the first or last time you tunnel vision :) Rubber Ducky Programming is a thing for a reason!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Don't be feeling stupid! Simple "gotcha" to miss and next time you forget, and you will forget, it will be the first thing you check

Answer (score 1):

You can lazy load the related entities as thus:

```
[InverseProperty("Incoming")]
public virtual UserDB From { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Outgoing")]
public virtual UserDB To { get; set; }
```

Or more recommended to eager load the entities on fetch from the database

```
var userDb = context.MessageDBs.Include(x => x.From).Include(x => x.To).FirstOrDefault();
```